# Converter um winform em webform

Tags: winforms, webforms

Eu tenho uma aplicação em um winForms eu preciso transformar este projeto em um WebForm para aplicação web, estou buscando saber se é possível e existe alguma  maneira de fazer isso.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ok, está editado!

Comment: Como eu já disse, não é possível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai precisar mudar (*criar sua aplicação do zero como uma aplicação web*) seguindo as regras que sua aplicação `winForms` tem.

Existem alguns tipos de aplicação para web como ( `web Forms, mvc, "web api"`), que você pode segui, muitas coisas mudam com isso, mas você pode abrir uma pergunta para cada duvida que tive em relação a isso.

Escolha o tipo de aplicação `WEB` que mais se encaixa com suas necessidades e siga os passos que o visual studio oferece para criação da aplicação, após isso e só seguir as regras que você tem na outra aplicação.

Não tem uma forma para converte sua aplicação WinForms para Web (que eu saiba).

Comment: pois é, acho que não tem jeito, vou ter que fazer isso mesmo, é que como eu comecei a mexer agora com c# e visual studio vai ser mais complicado, perguntei isso pra saber se tinha alguma forma mais "simples" de fazer, mas já que não tem.. mão na massa!! Valeu pela resposta!

Comment: Foi o que imaginei, veja pelo lado bom, vai aprender algumas coisas diferentes... como falei se tiver alguma duvida com algum método ou qualquer outra coisa da forma que é feito no `web forms` crie uma pergunta falando o que você tem como winforms e como ficaria em web forms. boa sorte :)

Comment: certo! Muito obrigada!